# How to send emails from django App in Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have created one Django Application,also hosted it on the google app engine. I can send emails from django application, but after hosting it to app engine I cant do that.I really stuck with this problem, so please tell me if there is any solution for using django  email functions in Google app engine.

I have tried  **appengine_django**  but it not working.

Django version 1.3.1

python  version 2.6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Django comes with an email backend that uses sendmail to send email.  Sendmail is not available on App Engine.

If you use Django-nonrel, it comes with an email backend that uses GAE's email service.
https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine, look in mail.py

As far as I know, it's only been tested to work with the entire Django-nonrel framework.  If you're using it without the rest of Django-nonrel, some hackery is required.

Comment: There is also a pluggable email backend that someone has created independent of djangoappengine, if you want a more lightweight / less hacked solution. It works at the time of this post, according to testing in my dev environment. https://bitbucket.org/andialbrecht/appengine_emailbackends/overview

Answer (score 2):

Google only allows you to send emails from a domain name that they control in the google app engine. So you will either have to send it from the test domain they give you, a gmail account, or you need to use their name servers for your domain name.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem solved.**

Just follow the link.
http://andialbrecht.de/blog/2009/11/04/pluggable-app-engine-e-mail-backends-for-django.html

I think this is the easiest method for using Django email functions in Google App Engine.

Comment: This page is down 404

Answer (score 2):

Yeah **appengine_django** does not work. you need to use **djangoappengine.mail.EmailBackend**
so your settings.py should have:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'djangoappengine.mail.EmailBackend'
```

Then you can use django's native send_mail function to send emails. I have myself tested it to  work.